# How to display a message on screen depending on the response from a saga handler

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Contact Saga handler

```
export function* handlePostContactUser(action) {
    try {
        yield call(axios.post, '*endpoint*', action.data);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Front-end form handleSubmit function:

```
let handleContactFormSubmit = () => {
     let name = input.name;
     let email = input.email;
     let message = input.message;
     dispatch({ type: 'POST_CONTACT_USER', data: {name, email, message, date}});
}
```

RootSaga

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
    yield all([
       takeEvery("POST_CONTACT_USER", handlePostContactUser)
    ]);
};
```

Based on this code, how could I display a message on the front end after the form submits, based on if it was successful or not? If it was, then just redirect/refresh the page, if not, display an error on the screen for the user to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sagas are basically generators, what you need to do is fire an action after the `yield call(axios)`. Change the store this way and get the result in your component.

In order to handle an error, put an action in the catch block doing the same thing.

```
export function* handlePostContactUser(action) {
    try {
        yield call(axios.post, '*endpoint*', action.data);
        yield put('MY_SUCCESS_ACTION')
    } catch (error) {
        yield put('MY_ERROR_ACTION')
    }
};
```

Update the store like this and then get the store properties that you need in the component.